# Получить первый день недели в текущей локализации?

Tags: c, локаль

Как стандартными средствами C получить первый день недели ? (То есть где то она может начинаться с понедельника/где то с воскресенья)

Comment: Вопрос переформулируйте. Если я правильно понял, нужно определить на какой день недели попадает первое число определенного месяца определенного года?

Comment: @gecube да вы правильно поняли. не могу вспомнить подходящей функции/структуры..

Comment: Вроде в стандартной библиотеке этого нет. WinAPI подойдет?

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов мне кажется что должно быть) нет надо под unix/linux

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/ - заполняем как нам нужно, а потом, скажем, вызываем http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/

Comment: @gecube черт я не внимательно прочитал вашу поправку - вы меня не так поняли.
я имел ввиду, что в некоторых локализациях неделя начинается с восекресенья:
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
а, например, в русской с понедельника:
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
Соответсвенно как это определить ?)

Comment: @pol, а зачем это Вам нужно?

Comment: @gecube я же сказал, что мы друг друга не поняли)

Comment: [Вот][1]. Я же говорю, что вопрос обсуждался.

 [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/125225/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B

Comment: @ХэшКод, я заметил, что наконец заперли создание новых меток. Однако, теперь было бы неплохо переименовать `[local]` в `[locale]` в этом и трёх(?) подобных вопросах.

Comment: Тэги поправил....